# Force show a record in PureScript

Tags: debugging, inspect, purescript

Is it possible to force-show (i.e., create a string representation) an arbitrary record in PureScript for debugging purpose regardless of it having a type-class instance for `Show`?

I would like to show the contents of the [Pux Event](http://www.alexmingoia.com/purescript-pux/docs/API/Pux/Html/Events.html#) object but it does not have a Show instance:

```
  No type class instance was found for

    Data.Show.Show { target :: { value :: String
                               , checked :: Boolean
                               }
                   , currentTarget :: { value :: String
                                      , checked :: Boolean
                                      }
                   , altKey :: Boolean
                   , button :: Number
                   , buttons :: Number
                   , clientX :: Number
                   , clientY :: Number
                   , ctrlKey :: Boolean
                   , metaKey :: Boolean
                   , pageX :: Number
                   , pageY :: Number
                   , screenX :: Number
                   , screenY :: Number
                   , shiftKey :: Boolean
                   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`purescript-debug`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-debug/2.0.0/docs/Debug.Trace).

Comment: Thanks Phil - is the shortest way to print record `{a:1}` doing this: `traceAny {a:1} id`?

Comment: Current version is `trace { a: 1} identity

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap a record in a `newtype` and use `Data.Generic` to derive the instance for it:

```
import Data.Generic

newtype MyRecord = MyRecord
                   { target :: { value :: String
                               , checked :: Boolean
                               }
                   , currentTarget :: { value :: String
                                      , checked :: Boolean
                                      }
                   , altKey :: Boolean
                   , button :: Number
                   , buttons :: Number
                   , clientX :: Number
                   , clientY :: Number
                   , ctrlKey :: Boolean
                   , metaKey :: Boolean
                   , pageX :: Number
                   , pageY :: Number
                   , screenX :: Number
                   , screenY :: Number
                   , shiftKey :: Boolean
                   }


derive instance genericMyRecord :: Generic MyRecord

instance showMyRecord :: Show MyRecord where
    show = gShow
```

Now you can use `show` on `MyRecord` or `show <<< MyRecord` on the record.