# Purescript default `Show` instance for records

Tags: purescript

I saw this question:

- [Force show a record in PureScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530747/force-show-a-record-in-purescript)

where I found out I can use purescript-debug to print it, e.g. by using:

```
> traceAny {a:1} id
{ a: 1 }
unit
```

I was wondering however what is the rationale behind not having a default `Show` instance for records:

```
> {a:1}
Error found:
in module $PSCI

  No type class instance was found for

    Data.Show.Show { "a" :: Int
                   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Show` is just implemented as library code, so there's no way an instance can be written that can accomodate every possible record. There would need to be some kind of constraint where you could say "the type of every value in this record must also have a `Show` instance", for example. The actual implementation would need to be somewhat magic too, since you can't iterate over the labels in a record either.

There have been a few discussions about reforming `Show`, [such as this one](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/1675), that would potentially solve this, by making `Show` entirely magic, and only usable for debugging purposes.

Although this doesn't really solve the case you have here, it is possible to rely on `Generic` deriving to make a `Show` instance for a `newtype`'d record, which can take some of the pain out of this kind of thing:

```
import Data.Generic (class Generic, gShow)

newtype MyRecord = MyRecord { a :: Int }

derive instance genericMyRecord :: Generic MyRecord

instance showMyRecord :: Show MyRecord where
  show = gShow
```

And if you derive `Newtype` too it makes the record easier to work with as you can use the various operations that help with wrapping/unwrapping/operating under the newtype, etc.

Comment: Thanks gb., I always thought of records as similar to primitive types.

Comment: How do you do this when your newtype/data declaration has a type variable? I.e. it's `* -> *` rather than just `*`.

Comment: You need to inclue a constraint on the type variable too. So instead of `instance name :: Class Type` you'd have `instance name :: Class a => Class (Type a)`.

Comment: Now in `Data.Show.Generic`: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.1/docs/Data.Show.Generic#t:GenericShow

Answer (score 1):

Instances are used to define blueprints for creating objects with similar properties.

`show` can be used to convert types into string type, but since types such as `Int`, `String`, etc already have a instance of show so we don't really have to define one but types which are user defined has no instances and we have to define one to actually use `show`.

on the other hand for debugging purpose we can use `spy` to print any types into console without actually defining instances.